# Populate a column with three different values based on four conditions

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have two sheets named `first` and `second` in a Sheets and would like to populate Status column with three different value based on these four conditions:

- First: if `B:B=0` --> **A**
- Second & Third: if `A:A<second!A2` and `(INDEX(A2:A,COUNT(A2:A)))<today()))` --> **C**
- Fourth: if `A:A<today()` --> **B**

*(If all three fail, leave empty.)*

These are the sample tables I am working on:

first

[image: first]

second

[image: second]

**The following are the desired results on respective tables.**

first

[image: d.first]

second

[image: d.second]

Here is what I have tried, but it says only less than three arguments are allowed.

```
=IF(B2>0, if(A2<today(), "B", ""), if(B2=0,"A", ""), IF((AND((A:A<second!A2),((INDEX(A2:A,COUNT(A2:A)))<today()))),"C",""))
```

Comment: Google spreadsheet is my preference. Thanks.

Comment: if the dates on 'first'(A:A) are older than first date of 'second'(A2) as well as the last date on 'first'(INDEX(G2:G; COUNT(G2:G))) are older than today(), set the value to C. You can think the values ABC as A=ignore, B=pending and C=done.

Answer (score 0):

Just made few small changes and it worked.

```
=if(B:B=0, "A", if(A:A<today(), IF((AND((A:A<second!A2),((INDEX(A2:A,COUNT(A2:A)))<today()))),"C","B"), ""))
```